# Jenkins plugin to manage cron/periodic build of multiple jobs?

Tags: linux, jenkins, cron, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins installation running several dozen NodeJs applications.

Currently, each job just builds on the GitHub webhook for the master branch.

I would also like to build each project periodically, once per day. I don't want to have to copy/paste the same cron into 30 job configurations, though - mostly because updates would become tedious.

I looked around and did not find any obvious plugin for managing shared cron patterns, etc.

Any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea here could have been to use a global variable defined at the level of Jenkins. Unfortunately the cron job field does not allow referencing a global variable.

However, there are multiple ways to achieve what you are aiming for.

The first solution is to create dummy job that has the schedule. This job will just trigger all the other jobs to run using the post build action `Build other projects`. That way you will only set the cron expression on the dummy job and all the other jobs will be triggered once the dummy job runs.

Another similar solution is to use `Build after other projects are built` option in Jenkins. You can set the cron schedule on one of the jobs that you have, and set the `Build after other projects are built` to build after the scheduled job has been built for the rest of the jobs. That way the "main" schedueled job will run and all the others will follow.